# What is the maximum facebook post limit I can get through get()

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What is the maximum facebook post limit  I can get through get()
Like using

```
$fb->get('/me/posts?limit=500');
```

I can get maximum 500 pages. What is the limit?

I have seen in the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging

limit : This is the number of individual objects that are returned in each page. Note that this is an upper limit, if there are not enough remaining objects in the list of data, then less than this number will be returned. Some edges have an upper maximum on the limit value, for performance reasons. We will return the correct pagination links if that happens.

Answer (score 0):

maximum of you can get the 500 posts,

My suggestion is user the limits then through pagination you can access all the pages.